# Is there any way to query products using dynamic filters in Magento 2.3 graphql endpoint?

Tags: graphql, magento2, magento-2.3

I was looking at the new graphql endpoint exposed by Magento 2.3.1 and above at the query for listing products:

```
query products(
    pageSize:6,
    currentPage:1,
    filter:{
        category_id: { eq: "3" }
    }

  ) {
    filters {
      name
      request_var
      filter_items_count
      filter_items {
        label value_string
      }
    }
    items {
      id
      name
      small_image {
        url
      }
      # ...
    }
    # ...
  }
```

The response body yields products in the `items` property just as expected and a bunch of custom filters in an array in the `filters` property which look like this:

```
"filters": [
        {
          "name": "Activity",
          "request_var": "activity",
          "filter_items_count": 12,
          "filter_items": [
            {
              "label": "Outdoor",
              "value_string": "5"
            },
            {
              "label": "Yoga",
              "value_string": "8"
            },
            {
              "label": "Recreation",
              "value_string": "9"
            },
            // rest of filter values
          ]
        },
        // rest of filters
]
```

Given the fact that those filters are dynamic and user defined is there a way of sending them back with a list products query in graphql? I would expect to have a property somewhere under the `products` query that could be an array of aforementioned filter objects but so far I haven't found anything neither in the schema nor in the official documentation.

Did anyone have any similar experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

No. Theres no way of getting the filtered options sent back. There are options where you can return the additional filtering abilities (similar to when you are viewing a category page) to return list of ways to filter but nothing that returns the current active filters in place.

```
     {
          products(filter: {sku: {like: "%"} }  pageSize: 500) {
            filters{
              request_var
              name
              filter_items{
                label
                value_string
              }
            }
            items {
              id
              sku
              name
              ...
            }
          }
     }
```

Comment: so how does one go about filtering products by... let's say the "color" property?